# Не могу отловить баг в коде MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android

Приложение для игры в крестики-нолики написал. Сделал так чтобы можно было засчитать победу. В коде вроде все понятно, дело в том что после победы не нажатые ImageView должны становиться некликабельными, в операторах if увидите как я это сделал. Суть в том что по нажатию на button все ImageView должны вновь стать активными (но все равно некоторые некликабельны), что делать, где баг ?

```
package com.example.user.tic_tac_toe;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView text;
    boolean bool = true;
    ImageView image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, image_5, image_6, image_7,
            image_8, image_9;
    Button button;
    int im1, im2, im3, im4, im5, im6, im7, im8, im9;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)
                findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        im1 = im2 = im3 = im4 = im5 = im6 = im7 = im8 = im9 = 0;
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        image_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1);

        image_1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.if_icon));
        image_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_2);

        image_2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.if_icon));
        image_3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_3);

        image_3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.if_icon));
        image_4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_4);

        image_4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.if_icon));
        image_5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_5);

        image_5.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.if_icon));
        image_6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_6);

        image_6.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.if_icon));
        image_7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_7);

        image_7.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.if_icon));
        image_8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_8);

        image_8.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.if_icon));
        image_9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_9);

        image_9.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.if_icon));
        final View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new
                View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        switch(view.getId()){
                            case R.id.image_1:
                                if(bool == true){
                                    image_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_cross);
                                    image_1.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                                    bool = false;
                                    image_1.setClickable(false);
                                    im1=1;
                                }else{
                                    image_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_circle);
                                    image_1.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                                    bool = true;
                                    image_1.setClickable(false);
                                    im1=2;
                                }break;
                            case R.id.image_2:
                                if(bool == true){
                                    image_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_cross);
                                    image_2.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                                    bool = false;
                                    image_2.setClickable(false);
                                    im2=1;
                                }else{
                                    image_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_circle);
                                    image_2.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                                    bool = true;
                                    image_2.setClickable(false);
                                    im2=2;
                                }break;
                            case R.id.image_3:
                                if(bool == true){
                                    image_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_cross);
                                    image_3.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                                    bool = false;
                                    image_3.setClickable(false);
                                    im3=1;
                                }else{
                                    image_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_circle);
                                    image_3.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                                    bool = true;
                                    image_3.setClickable(false);
                                    im3=2;
                                }break;
                            case R.id.image_4:
                                if(bool == true){
                                    image_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_cross);
                                    image_4.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                                    bool = false;
                                    image_4.setClickable(false);
                                    im4=1;
                                }else{
                                    image_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_circle);
                                    image_4.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                                    bool = true;
                                    image_4.setClickable(false);
                                    im4=2;
                                }break;
                            case R.id.image_5:
                                if(bool == true){
                                    image_5.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_cross);
                                    image_5.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                                    bool = false;
                                    image_5.setClickable(false);
                                    im5=1;
                                }else{
                                    image_5.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_circle);
                                    image_5.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                                    bool = true;
                                    image_5.setClickable(false);
                                    im5=2;
                                }break;
                            case R.id.image_6:
                                if(bool == true){
                                    image_6.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_cross);
                                    image_6.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                                    bool = false;
                                    image_6.setClickable(false);
                                    im6=1;
                                }else{
                                    image_6.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_circle);
                                    image_6.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                                    bool = true;
                                    image_6.setClickable(false);
                                    im6=2;
                                }break;
                            case R.id.image_7:
                                if(bool == true){
                                    image_7.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_cross);
                                    image_7.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                                    bool = false;
                                    image_7.setClickable(false);
                                    im7=1;
                                }else{
                                    image_7.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_circle);
                                    image_7.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                                    bool = true;
                                    image_7.setClickable(false);
                                    im7=2;
                                }break;
                            case R.id.image_8:
                                if(bool == true){
                                    image_8.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_cross);
                                    image_8.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                                    bool = false;
                                    image_8.setClickable(false);
                                    im8=1;
                                }else{
                                    image_8.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_circle);
                                    image_8.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                                    bool = true;
                                    image_8.setClickable(false);
                                    im8=2;
                                }break;
                            case R.id.image_9:
                                if(bool == true){
                                    image_9.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_cross);
                                    image_9.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                                    bool = false;
                                    image_9.setClickable(false);
                                    im9=1;
                                }else{
                                    image_9.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_circle);
                                    image_9.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                                    bool = true;
                                    image_9.setClickable(false);
                                    im9=2;
                                }break;
                        }
                        if(im1 == 1 && im2 == 1 && im3 == 1){
                            text.setText("RED WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_5.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im4 == 1 && im5 == 1 && im6 == 1){
                            text.setText("RED WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im7 == 1 && im8 == 1 && im9 == 1){
                            text.setText("RED WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_5.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im1 == 1 && im4 == 1 && im7 == 1){
                            text.setText("RED WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                            image_5.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im2 == 1 && im5 == 1 && im8 == 1){
                            text.setText("RED WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im3 == 1 && im6 == 1 && im9 == 1){
                            text.setText("RED WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_5.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im1 == 1 && im5 == 1 && im9 == 1){
                            text.setText("RED WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im3 == 1 && im5 == 1 && im7 == 1){
                            text.setText("RED WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im1 == 2 && im2 == 2 && im3 == 2){
                            text.setText("BLUE WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_5.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im4 == 2 && im5 == 2 && im6 == 2){
                            text.setText("BLUE WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im7 == 2 && im8 == 2&& im9 == 2){
                            text.setText("BLUE WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_5.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im1 == 2 && im4 == 2 && im7 == 2){
                            text.setText("BLUE WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                            image_5.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im2 == 2 && im5 == 2 && im8 == 2){
                            text.setText("BLUE WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im3 == 2 && im6 == 2 && im9 == 2){
                            text.setText("BLUE WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_5.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im1 == 2 && im5 ==2 && im9 == 2){
                            text.setText("BLUE WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_7.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_3.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        if(im3 == 2 && im5 == 2 && im7 == 2){
                            text.setText("BLUE WIN");
                            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            image_4.setClickable(false);
                            image_2.setClickable(false);
                            image_6.setClickable(false);
                            image_1.setClickable(false);
                            image_8.setClickable(false);
                            image_9.setClickable(false);
                        }
                        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                switch (view.getId()){
                                    case R.id.button:
                                        bool = true;
                                        image_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_icon);
                                        image_1.setClickable(true);
                                        image_2.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_icon);
                                        image_2.setClickable(true);
                                        image_3.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_icon);
                                        image_3.setClickable(true);
                                        image_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_icon);
                                        image_4.setClickable(true);
                                        image_5.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_icon);
                                        image_5.setClickable(true);
                                        image_6.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_icon);
                                        image_6.setClickable(true);
                                        image_7.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_icon);
                                        image_7.setClickable(true);
                                        image_8.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_icon);
                                        image_8.setClickable(true);
                                        image_9.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_icon);
                                        image_9.setClickable(true);
                                        image_1.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                                        image_2.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                                        image_3.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                                        image_4.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                                        image_5.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                                        image_6.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                                        image_7.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                                        image_8.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                                        image_9.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
        image_1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        image_2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        image_3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        image_4.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        image_5.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        image_6.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        image_7.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        image_8.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        image_9.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: основная ваша проблема  - архитектура. если вы изучите паттерн MVC, то сможете существенно улучши дизайн вашей программы и избежать некоторого количества ошибок.

Answer (score 1):

1) присваивание

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}
```

Находится в слушателе каждого image

```
final View.OnClickListener onClickListener
```

Что явно не правильно.
2) Вообще не нужные строки, скорее всего из-за них и не работает.

```
switch (view.getId()){
   case R.id.button:
```